# Notepad++ - Code Folding do not show last line

Tags: notepad++, code-folding

How can I configure Notepad++  to see last line of code fold block.

example:

```
<form id="myForm" action="login.asp">
    /*100 input tags*/
</form>
```

I would like to see the initial and final line to assure that the block is correct, final line too:

```
<form id="myForm" action="login.asp">
</form>
```

By default Notepad++ only show the initial line:

```
<form id="myForm" action="login.asp">
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that, in Npp the folding allways hide the last line.

Comment: I would be amazed if you can do this :( You may have more luck if you use `regions` but that may mean updating the HTML

Comment: A pity that can not be seen. It would be very useful, at least for the distrustful ones with oneself like me. If I do not see the last line I did not trust that I did it right :-)

Comment: What I started doing to circumvent this is to add a comment line `<!-- End of <\form>  -->` after closing tag. This way, when I fold the tag, I can know that it actually folded at the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to this which works fairly well.

Add a comment line `<!-- End of <\form>  -->` after closing tag.
This way, when you fold the tag, you can know that it actually folded at the right location.
Here is a gif for it. Hope it helps.

[image]